# Oracle Regex remove duplicates

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a requirement to remove duplicate values from a comma separated string.

```
Input String: a,a,a,b,c,a,b
Expected output: a,b,c
```

What I have tried:

```
with ct(str) as(
select 'a,a,a,b,c,a,b' from dual
)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,)','\1\3') col from ct

Output: a,b,c,a,b
```

The above query can remove repetitive characters which are consecutive.

I know that the above requirement can be solved by creating a table out of the comma separated values and do a `listagg` on the distinct values.

Is it possible to achieve the above requirement using a single regex statement?.

Comment: Probably not. This question has been asked on SO (and other discussion boards) numerous times, and no one has found a solution with a single REGEXP call. Do you require a rigorous (mathematical) proof that such a solution does not exist, at least with Oracle's implementation of regular expressions? That may be pretty tough.

Comment: With .NET, PyPi regex, it is possible, but Oracle regex does not support lookarounds.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks.. I will try to split the comma separated values to rows and select distinct values from them.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the required result:

```
     with borken as (SELECT distinct column_value as str,'1' cnt FROM 
     table(apex_string.split('a,a,a,b,c,a,b' ,','))  )
     select listagg(str,',') within group (order by cnt) from borken;
```

Comment: Thanks. I know this can be achieved using an intermediate table. But I was looking for a solution implemented  regex alone.